# Powernap daemon doesn't start with upstart

Tags: kubuntu, upstart, powernap

I have a problem with powernap daemon on kubuntu 13.04, which doesn't start with upstart (or with `/etc/init.d/powernap start`). On my other machine with ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS it starts ok.

```
$ sudo service powernap start
powernap stop/pre-start, process 8245
$ sudo service powernap status
powernap stop/waiting
```

I tried reinstalling powernap (with purge), but the problem persists.
The only way i managed to start powernap daemon is:

```
$ sudo powernapd
$ ps -e | grep powernap
21369 ?        00:00:00 powernapd
```

The system is up-to-date.

Comment: Hey same problem with me also . I am also using the same Kubuntu 13.04 .

Answer (score 0):

from the `service --status -all` command I have found something which can help you.

```
21369 ?        00:00:00 powernapd
```

here `?` is status of your service and i.e The [ ? ] is drawn for services that do not support the service command. Support for this command is determined by grepping the "Usage" information that is printed when service $SERVICE is run.

so you can not check its status with service powernap status command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Edit this file: `/etc/default/powernap`

Contents:

```
# start powernap at boot [yes|no]
START=yes
```

I don't understand why but start was set to no, change it to yes and it works!